# Re-arrange NSArray and NSDictionary entries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have array with nsdictionary objects, for ex.:

```
({"someKey" = "title";
  "name" = "someName";
 },
 {"someKey" = "title";
  "name" = "anotherName";
 }
 {"someKey" = "newTitle";
  "name" = "someName";
 }
)
```

Please, help me to sort it in this format:

```
({"someKey" = "title";
  "names": (
    {"name" = "someName"},
    {"name" = "anotherName"}
  )
 },
 {"someKey" = "newTitle";
  "names": (
   {"name" = "someName"}
  )
 }
)
```

Thanks..

Comment: That's not sorting, that totally new layout. What have you tried?

Comment: That's not sorted; that's re-arranged.

Comment: First sort your array based on "someKey".  Then compare adjacent entries, and if two adjacent entries have the same "someKey" value, combine them into one.  It's just programming, not rocket science.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i understand from your question you want to pick individual objects into one single dictionary object..

```
NSArray *yourArray=.... /* array which contains this data: ({"someKey" = "title";
  "name" = "someName";
 },
 {"someKey" = "title";
  "name" = "anotherName";
 }
)*/
NSMutableDictionary *newDictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];

for(int i=0;i<[yourArray count];i++){
    [newDictionary setObject:[yourArray objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"names"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ({"someKey" = "title";
 "name" = "someName";
 },
   {"someKey" = "title";
  "name" = "anotherName";
 }
)
```

Assuming above  is equivalent to

```
NSArray *array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dictionary1,dictionary2,nil];
```

then to achieve below result

```
  (
{
 "someKey" = "title";
"names": (
 {"name" = "someName"},
{"name" = "anotherName"}
  )
 }
)
```

We have  this :

```
 //Get name array 
 NSMutableArray *names=[NSMutableArray array];

 for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)
 {
     NSDictionary *dictionary=[array objectAtIndex:i];
     [names addObject:[dictionary valueForKey:@"name"];
 }


 NSDictionary *newDictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithOjbectsAndKeys:@"someKey",@"title",names,@"names",nil];

//Your final result is an array with one object ( A Dictionary )

NSArray *finalArray=[NSArray arrayWithObjects: newDictionary,nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to traverse the current structure and build a new dictionary with the title as the unique key:

```
NSEnumerator* arrayEnumerator = [myArray objectEnumerator];

NSDictionary* = dictFromArray;

NSMutableArray* titleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary* titleDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

while(dictFromArray = [arrayEnumerator nextObject])
{
    currentTitle = [dictFromArray objectForKey:@"someKey"];
    currentName = [dictFromArray objectForKey:@"name"];

    if([titles containsObject:currentTitle)
    {
    NSMutableDictionary namesArray = [titleDict objectForKey:currentTitle];
    [namesArray addObject:currentName];
    }
    else
    {
        [titles addObject:currentTitle];
        [titleDict addObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:currentName] forKey:currentTitle];
    }
}
```

This should give you a dictionary that looks like:

```
{
    title = 
    (
        someName,
        anotherName
    );

    newTitle = 
    (
        someName
    )
}
```

To get the exact structure you have above, I think this should work:

```
NSArray* titleKeys = [titleDict allKeys];

NSEnumerator* keyEnumerator = [titleKeys objectEnumerator];
NSMutableArray* finalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString* key;

while (key = [keyEnumerator nextObject])
{
    [finalArray addObject: [NSDictionary 
        dictionaryWithObjects:(key, [dictArray objectForKey:key])
        forKeys:(@"someKey", @"names")]];
}
```